# Multidimensional Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How do i add items into a multidimensional array? Basically i am making an application which calculates what people are buying in a suppermarket and how much of it.

> Sue buys 2 tubs of butter and 1.
>   toothpaste
>
> John buys 1 peach and 1 banana.

I think the array would look something like this

```
$sue[butter] = array(); 
$sue[butter][] = 2;
$sue[toothpaste] = array(); 
$sue[toothpaste][] = 1;
$john[peach] = array(); 
$john[peach][] = 1;
$john[banana] = array(); 
$john[banana][] = 1;
```

My current code can only record the item and the item quantity.

```
public $items = array();

public function AddItem($product_id)
{
    if (array_key_exists($product_id , $this->items))
    {
        $this->items[$product_id] = $this ->items[$product_id] + 1;
    } else {
        $this->items[$product_id] = 1;
    }
}
```

I just dont know how to put this inside an array for each person.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're already using a shopping cart class, so Zack's answer should fit right in. I'd recommend making $items private (or protected) rather than public, and adding an accessor function.

Comment: This question lacks a clear [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this, you might find it easier to encapsulate into a class. For instance, have each person be a class, and then give them attributes.

Once you get into multidimensional arrays, it becomes more difficult to maintain your code.

For instance (this is pseudocode):

```
class Customer {
    //this is an array of FoodItem objects.
    private $foodItems[];

    // any other methods needed for access here
}

class FoodItem {
    //could be a String, or whatever it needs to be
    private $itemType;

    //the number of that item purchased
    private $numPurchased;
}
```

Comment: Hi Zack, i need it in an array because i am saving it in a session between my pages! But thanks anyway!

Comment: Just FYI, you can save classes/objects in session data. Saving to the data serialized your variable. See http://us.php.net/serialize

Comment: Hi Rob! i was using searilized for my origianal array! I wasnt aware this could be used for more than just arrays, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: PHP will serialize/unserialize for you, as long as the class definition is loaded or can be autoloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Hm, maybe I fail to see the multi-dimensionality here?

```
$sue = array();
$sue['butter'] = 2;
$sue['toothpaste'] = 1;

$john = array();
$john['peach'] = 1;
$john['banana'] = 1;
```

I think the function you've shown would work with the above.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, I think your multidimensional array is what i was actually trying to write. I'm just not sure how to set this using my method above!

Comment: @Ben McRae: I think there is a misapprehension on your side. :) My array is not multidimensional at all. It has one dimension of keys and values. And the function you use now would actually work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create another array to hold the number of items like you did here:

```
$sue[butter] = array(); 
$sue[butter][] = 2;
```

I think something like this would work:

```
$customers[sue][butter] = 2; 
$customers[sue][toothpaste] = 1; 
$customers[john][peach] = 1; 
$customers[john][banana] = 1;
```

This way you create an array of customer names. Then in each customer array you have an array of their products. Then each product holds the number of that product the customer bought.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$data["persons"] = array("Sue","John");
$data["articles"] = array("butter","toothpaste","peach","banana");

$data["carts"] = array();

$data["carts"][0][0] = 2; // sue's 2 butter packets
$data["carts"][0][1] = 1; // sue's 1 tooth paste

$data["carts"][1][2] = 1; // john's peach
$data["carts"][1][3] = 1; // john's banana
```